# Setting Pixels Band Values

Tags: raster, multi-band

I have a single band RASTER of an area, in which I want to create 360 bands and then assign those bands values from a table.  Is there a process for doing this?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to write each of the 600 bands into their own ASCII Grid files http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GEOTOOLS/ArcInfo+ASCII+Grid+format. Format is plain text and easy to produce from the table. When individual bands are ready you can write them a single 600-band geotiff file with GDAL. Build first a virtual raster file that combines the bands http://www.gdal.org/gdal_vrttut.html. Gdalbuildvrt tool will help you http://www.gdal.org/gdalbuildvrt.html. Use the -separate switch.